# Maintain aspect ratio of a view on a NSWindow, rather than the aspect.

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nsimageview

I have an image view that i would like to maintain the aspect ratio of but still be able to resize the window.

Comment: Scalling "Proportionally Up or Down" ?

Answer (score 3):

Set the image view scaling property to "proportionally up or down" in interface builder and set the content aspect ratio of the window containing it:

```
        [window setContentAspectRatio:myImageView.image.size];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there's no way to do this "automatically", you'll need to follow the frame change of the window (with the delegate method windowWillResize:toSize:) and adjust your image view's frame however you want it to change.